# International flight

Tags: customs-and-immigration

This is my first time flying international and I need to know the process. I'm flying Delta airlines from Pittsburgh to MSP, catching a connecting flight to Haneda Airport, Japan, then catching a flight to ITM with All Nippons Airways.I need to know the process step by step. Thank you.

Comment: So, what do you want to know? Your "question" at the moment is *massive* in scope...

Comment: Not so very different from domestic flying. Extra steps are going through Customs and Immigration and airports are built so you that you can't help but go through the process in the right sequence. Be reassured that it is in the interests of the airline and airport that everything goes smoothly for you, so if you get lost or confused, ask staff.

Comment: If you need a more step by step set of instructions than in the answer already given, you may want to travel with someone. The answer is good, where it does not give steps is because while traveling you do not need steps.

Answer (score 5):

The most unfamiliar thing for you will be in Tokyo/Haneda, and then in Osaka/Itami. Fortunately both are relatively small airports (compared to the other possible route, to Tokyo/NRT and Osaka/KIX).

[Haneda Airport's International to Domestic Transfer](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/dept/int_dms.html) page will be of interest to you. Basically the steps are:

- Immigration. You will enter the country in Tokyo.
- Luggage pick-up and Customs. Japan is quite strict on what you can bring in to the country. Especially medicine. Customs check is mandatory (not random like in most countries).
- Transfer to the domestic terminal: in your case T2. Take the shuttle bus. It is the most convenient.
- Check-in for your domestic flight. Pass through security. Board your flight.

May I suggest that while you're in Haneda International arrivals hall, you withdraw some money [from an ATM](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/bank.html#atm), or change cash (exchange rate isn't too good though).

For ITM, check out [this page](https://www.osaka-airport.co.jp/en/map/1f/) and [this map (PDF)](https://www.osaka-airport.co.jp/sites/all/themes/itm/pdf/en/map/floor_guide.pdf). Depending on where you're going in Osaka, if they're not picking you up, you can take [the train](https://www.osaka-airport.co.jp/en/access/train), or [the bus](https://www.osaka-airport.co.jp/en/access/bus). Avoid taking a taxi, unless you're super wealthy, or on a gold-plated expense account.

Finally, I would recommend to order [a prepaid SIM card](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/product.html) before you leave the US, and [pick it up at Haneda](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/aps_top.html) (if you have the time to drop by T1 first), or [at your hotel](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/delivery_hotels.html). This will make your life much easier (if you have an unlocked phone, of course...).

Comment: +1, but HND is actually over 2x large as NRT...!